# Table Tennis Edge Protectors

Tags: rules, table-tennis

I'm getting ready to purchase a table tennis table.
Some of the tables have plastic edge protectors that extend anywhere from an 1/8 to 3/8 of an inch off the corners of the table.
They are angled down a bit, but it still looks like a ball could hit them.
What are the rules here?
Would that be considered in bounds if hit?
If not, is it easy to discern if a ball hits it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume when you say 'corners' you mean the vertical edges of the table rather than the top surface? Firstly it is unlikely that the ball will hit the edge or corner and you won't be able to determine if the ball was in or out, and so I don't think the protectors will make much of a difference here. I have had a table for 10+ years without protectors and it's been fine.
To clarify, when the ball hits the edge and it bounces 90 degrees to the side or upwards from that angle, it is up/in play, and below 90 degrees is considered down/out of play. You could take the protectors off if they eventually annoy you or it disrupts the play but I am pretty sure it won't matter.

If you can include a photo in your question perhaps just to make sure I am not mistaken in your question that would be ideal.